# Offline password expiry when epoch date time is in future

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

**I am building app in Ionic and my phone does not have any network connectivity.**

I have built login module which has 6 month password expiry. I am using epoch time to store and compare. 
My simple strategy is : 
1. Save the next 6 month epoch with Date.now() when user set up PIN first time.
2. when user click on login, check weather (expiryPinDate - currDate)>6 if not ask user to reset password.

Now here comes flaw : If my password is expiring today, I will change my device's date to previous 6 month and I am still able to login in app. How I can do this offline by storing todays date or something like this. I dont have any access to any network and I am completely dependent on phone's date.

My pin expiry checking function is like this :

```
checkPinExpiry(){
       const expiryPinDate = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('expiry_PinDate'));
        return Date.now() < expiryPinDate;
                }
```